# @#variable meaning in php?

Tags: php

What is the meaning of `@#variable` in php ?

```
$fix=@#parts;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@ is used to suppress any errors that may occur on this line of the code

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

> When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might
>   be generated by that expression will be ignored.

I would not recommend using it at all because this may result in failure of noticing some  important error/warning and make debugging a havoc. On a production environment use error_reporting setting that will prevent any errors or warning from showing up while on a development server I would recommend to turn on any error reporting

Answer (score 5):

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When
>   prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be
>   generated by that expression will be ignored.

Link : [PHP.net explanation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Answer (score 1):

The `@`operator turns off error handling.